# p:fileUpload is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces  to upload photos. Its fine working in mozilla,chrome,safari browzer. The problem i am facing is its not work properly in internet explorer. Multiple image upload are not supported and faces messages are not shown in IE. Sometimes file path not fetch. java.io.FileNotFoundException are occured during upload image in IE

Jsf Pages for image upload:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120" />
    </h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:panel  header="Upload Photos" id="getImageId" style="font- size:12px;height:499px">
            <p:messages id="messages" for="imaload"></p:messages>
                 <p:fileUpload id="imaload" fileUploadListener="#{ngoPhotoUpload.photoUpload}"  
                           mode="advanced"  multiple="true" immediate="true"
                          update="messages" 
                           allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>

                 </p:panel>
                </h:form>
           </f:view>
       </h:body>
    </html>
```

I am using primefaces 3.0 and jsf 2.0. How can i solve it.

Comment: Try to upgrade to atleast 3.2 version (there where some IE related bug fix)

Comment: Quote from Primefaces User Guide: 
"Rich upload functionality like dragdrop from filesystem, multi uploads, progress tracking requires
browsers that implement HTML5 features so advanced mode might behave differently across
browsers and gracefully degrade for legacy browsers like IE. It is also suggested to offer simple
upload mode to the users of your application as a fallback."